# Mailchimp embed code not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I was trying to embed a sign up form in my wordpress website. what i did is like this: i went to the wordpress editor for that page and choose the option to add raw html code. Then pasted the below code:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://luisaspagnolistanford.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3b43aec3c5c107948b570c43d&amp;id=b67bd69928" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <label for="mce-EMAIL">Get notified about events and sales</label>
      <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3b43aec3c5c107948b570c43d_b67bd69928" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Then the design is coming fine and i can see all the code is there from inspect element option of chrome but when clicked the submit button it doesnt do anything and also there is no error. I am just wondering whats wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target="_blank"` this means that form response opens up in a new tab. Look for the tab.

You have a script in your `core-scripts.js` file that's preventing default behavior. Remove it.

```
$( "#mc-embedded-subscribe-form" ).submit(function( e ){
    var $this = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no pop up or new tab there. please check here [link](http://luisaspagnolistanford.com/)

Comment: thanks for this, I don't have access to that file right now but all I had to do was give my form a new id and it worked.